# Python Selenium issues on Windows Docker Container when hitting our production URL

Tags: python, docker, selenium, security, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to Docker Containers so I'm hoping someone can point out the issue to why a selenium test I have always fails on my docker container when trying to find elements on our production URL.

I'm trying to run a login test simultaneously on several docker containers for our web application. The test works perfectly for both our develop and production URL when running it on my host machine, but only passes when hitting the develop URL on the docker container. Specifically selenium throws a `Timeout` exception when trying to find the first element in the script (the username bar on the login page). It doesn't throw an error when I get the url itself, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of security measures happening that is recognizing that there is a VM device trying to scrape elements on the page. Since the test works for one url in the docker container (and both on my host machine), I'm fairly sure the code should work, and it is some security issue. However, below is a description of the code and stacktrace I'm receiving.

The way the test is set-up, a pytest fixture  is passed to the testcase which has the browser info (chrome browser) and the app info (includes an instance of our "application class" which sets the url, login information, etc. to match the environment: Dev/Prod for the web-app). The testcase then tries to login by calling the login function. This utilizes a customized find function which finds a list of elements which match a css-selector. We want the first element of this list, so we add the index `[0]` to the end of the find statement like so: `our_test_objects_browser.find('our_element')[0]`. More specifically here is the login function (from our login class) that is called and fails when finding the `self.user` element:

```
    def login(self):
        self.browser.get(self.obc.obcUrl)
        search_form = self.browser.find(self.user)[0]
        search_form.clear()
        search_form.send_keys(self.obc.username)
        search_form = self.browser.find(self.password)[0]
        search_form.clear()
        search_form.send_keys(self.obc.password)
        search_form.submit()
```

The testcase that calls this method is below:

```
def test_valid_login(obj_to_test):
        start_time=time.time()
        obj_to_test.login()
        print("run_time is" +str(time.time()-start_time())
```

And here is the stacktrace for the failure:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_valid_login _______________________________

obj_to_test = <obc.login.login.Login object at 0x0000026833AFD820>

    def test_valid_login(obj_to_test):
            start_time=time.time()
>           obj_to_test.login()

tests\obc\test_login.py:23:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
src\obc\login\login.py:25: in login
    search_form = self.browser.find(self.user)[0]
src\common\selenium_test.py:61: in find
    return (self.wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located(
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="035a9153594f3ebe92663c5e4bc9b121")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located object at 0x0000026833ACAC10>
message = ''

    def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80: TimeoutException
============================== warnings summary ===============================
tests/obc/test_login.py::test_valid_login
  c:\python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:997: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'flexonboardingn1.paychex.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
    warnings.warn(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
======================== 1 failed, 1 warning in 52.50s ========================
```

Comment: Additional info: Our production url includes a load balancer, where our dev url does not

Comment: We are trying to investigate a slowdown in our production url. we've noticed the login page takes a while to load (on occasion). This could be what is throwing the error on the docker container, but why does it happen everytime from the container?

Comment: I am assuming, the URL is private and you cannot share. Did you looked into the running container through VNC viewer https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#debugging or attaching a shell to it and reading the selenium server logs?